# Logback list properties configured via xml

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm writing my own Layout and I want to have ability to pass it list of values from config file.

My layout code:

```
public class MyPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

    private ArrayList<String> test;

    public ArrayList<String> getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(ArrayList<String> test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        return test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); //temporary, for testing purposes only
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="rpost.MyPatternLayout">
                <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{40}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
                <test>value 1</test>
                <test>value 2</test>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Example above is not working - it prints nothing.

Is it possible to configure list properties? How can it be done?

Comment: Did you figure out this one? I had a similar requirement to pass a list of properties to my custom appender. The only alternative I see is passing delimited values.

Comment: Yes, see answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found following solution:

Configuration (the same as in question):

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="rpost.MyPatternLayout">
                <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{40}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
                <test>value 1</test>
                <test>value 2</test>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Java code:

```
public class MyPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

    private List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTest(String test) {
        this.test.add(test);
    }

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        return test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); //temporary, for testing purposes only
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks god, you are genies